# How to upload an image coming from the Ionic's Camera to firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire, ionic-native

I've managed to take a picture using Ionic camera API:

```
  async pickImage(sourceType: CameraSource) {
    const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 90,
      allowEditing: true,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
      source: sourceType,
    });
    console.log(image);
  }
```

which gives me this:

[image]

I've also found that to upload using angular fire storage, but I can't figure out how to connect the two. I don't really understand what are the format in between, what format I should ask to the Camera API and what format should I provide to the AngularFireStorage API.

I tried this:

```
const filePath = 'name-your-file-path-here';
const ref = this.storage.ref(filePath);
const task = ref.put(image.webPath);
task
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(finalize(() => console.log(ref.getDownloadURL())))
  .subscribe();
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseStorageError: {"code_":"storage/invalid-argument","message_":"Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.","serverResponse_":null,"name_":"FirebaseError"}
```

Your lights would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: I hope someone will be patient enough to write you the boilerplate. My comment would be - in general you dont ask for format. It returns what returns. `Camera.getPhoto({` Obviously returns a Promise, which you could convert into Observable if needed. Same with Firebase - either its a Promise or Observable, they both can be converted to each other

Comment: @Bitman yeah, but `Camera.getPhoto` get a format(DATA_URL, FILE_URI or NATIVE_URI), then the promises returns a different value. And it's the same for the AngularFireStorage, there are different values accepted. I know about observable. If you check the code I provided, it `await`s on the observable, but I don't know how to convert  this Object to the one accepted by angularFireAuth. So no, the question has nothing to do with Promise/Observable/async.

Comment: Well, it does. Because you `await`'ing for it, what you get then is a resolved Promise result. Without `async` and `await` you can convert this Promise to an Observable

Comment: Totally right, but I still don't understand how knowing how to convert a promise to an observable helps me knowing which format I should ask to `Camera.getPhoto`, which method to call on the angularFireStorage, and what conversion should I do.

Comment: What I remember is that `angularfire` uses Observables, while native firebase uses Promises. If you use `angularfire`, obviously working with Observables might be easier. However thats all I can help. Hopefully someone can track you along this road because there is quite a bit to understand. I would recommend to share what you tried, so would be easier for others to help

Comment: @Bitman: Well, I know how to subscribe to observable and promises, but I don't know which method and which parameters to use, this is what this question is about.

Answer (score 2):

that "webpath" is not a file or a blob, you need to convert it before you call the put. There is an example of how to convert it on the ionic website

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/3-saving-photos

```
private async readAsBase64(cameraPhoto: CameraPhoto) {
  // Fetch the photo, read as a blob, then convert to base64 format
  const response = await fetch(cameraPhoto.webPath!);
  const blob = await response.blob();

  return await this.convertBlobToBase64(blob) as string;  
}

convertBlobToBase64 = (blob: Blob) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader;
  reader.onerror = reject;
  reader.onload = () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I've seen your name quite some times while searching for a solution :). But is there a way to NOT convert it in a base64 string? I read at multiple places that it was quite a costly operation and technically I don't understand why it's required to convert to base64 before sending the blob ?

Comment: after you get the blob, you can pass it to firebase and upload... you don't have to use the string

Comment: Check my code, it's what I was trying to do, but I get an error.

Comment: I'm running into this exact same thing. I would honestly be fine uploading even the base64 data but I get this error no matter what I try with firebase web sdk 9 from ios. This works fine coming from a localhost ionic app in browser but breaks in ios when trying to use photo.path instead of photo.webPath. Any luck with figuring this out?

Answer (score 1):

here is my sample code and its working fine, hope it helps

```js
ambilpoto2(){
    const image =  Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 90,
      allowEditing: true,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
    });
    image.then((res:any)=>{
      this.gambar = res.webPath;
      this.gambarnya.nativeElement.src = this.gambar;
      this.blob=this.readAsBase64(this.gambar);
      console.log(this.blob); 
    })
  }

  private async readAsBase64(cameraPhoto: any) {
    const response = await fetch(cameraPhoto);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    return await this.convertBlobToBase64(blob) as string;  
  }
  
  convertBlobToBase64 = (blob: Blob) => 
    new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader;
      reader.onerror = reject;
      reader.onload = () => {
          resolve(reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
  }
```

and here my code for php server

```html
//get base64 of image from client end
    $imageBase64 = $post['poto'];
    if ($imageBase64!='') {
        //function call
        $unique_name = uploadbase64image($imageBase64);
    }
    function uploadbase64image($base64) {
        $direktori = "domain/api/upload/"; 
        $imgname= $direktori.date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . ".png";
        $new_image_url ="upload/". $imgname;
        $base641 = 'data:image/png;base64,' . $base64;
        $base642 = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $base64));
        file_put_contents($new_image_url, $base642);
        return $uniname;
    }
```

with DataUrl Result Type

```html
ambilpoto(){
    const image =  Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 90,
      allowEditing: true,
      resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl
    });
    image.then((res:any)=>{
      this.gambar = res.dataUrl;this.gambarnya.nativeElement.src = this.gambar;
      console.log(this.gambar); 
    })
    
  }
```

```
enter code here
```