# while uploading image to backend server in vue.js got Request failed with status code 500

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor

I am getting Request failed with status code 500 error while uploading image(more than 1MB size) into backend server. But when i tried lessthan 1 mb image is working.
Here is the image uplaod function.

```js
async takeImage() {
  const capturedImage = await Camera.getPhoto({
    resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
    source: CameraSource.Prompt,
    quality: 100
  });
  const imageUrl = capturedImage.webPath;
  let blob = await fetch(imageUrl).then((r) => r.blob());
  console.log("imageUrl", blob);
  this.uploadImage(blob);
}

async uploadImage(event) {
  const url =
    "xxx";
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", event);
  axios
    .post(url, formData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: "xxxx"
      },
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        maxContentLength: Infinity,
        timeout: 120000
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
}
```

The error response.

> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: What is the content of the `event`? Usually you would want to provide the file content to the `append()` method, not an event

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan..The event is captured image.
async takeImage() {
      const capturedImage = await Camera.getPhoto({
        resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
        source: CameraSource.Prompt,
        quality: 100
      });
      console.log(capturedImage);
      this.uploadImage(capturedImage);
    }

Comment: Ok, then that is the issue. That's not the content which needs to be sent to the server. I'm not familiar with Vue/Ionic but hopefully this will help: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/saving-photos. It details how to save it to the local filesystem. The important part for your use case is to create the Blob and provide that to FormData. *Edit* - and also possibly this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75731985/519413

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan..Any idea how to send big size images( more than 2mb) files.

Comment: That would depend on the configuration of your server. Research how to change the max request size limit.